# Is it possible to add index values to the rows of a postgreSQL query when expanding JSON array with json_array_elements?

Tags: sql, json, postgresql, dbt

I have a database of resume data in json format which I am trying to transform.
One of the sections in each jsib is work_history, this is in the form of a json array i.e.

```
"work_experience":[
   {
      "job_title":"title",
      "job_description":"description"
   },
   {
      "job_title":"title",
      "job_description":"description"
   }
]
```

I am iterating over each resume (json file) and importing this data into a new table using dbt and postgreSQL with each element of the array being a new row with the associated metadata of the resume. Here is the code I used for this

```
select
    json_array_elements(rjt.raw_json::json -> 'data' -> 'work_experience')  as we,
    json_array_elements(rjt.raw_json::json -> 'data' -> 'work_experience') -> 'job_title' as "name",
    rjt.uuid as uuid
from raw_json_table rjt
```

The last thing that I need to do is add a column that lists the index that each job came from within its individual workexperience array i.e. if a job was the third element in the array it would have a 2 in the "source_location" column. How can I generate this index such that it starts at 0 for each new json file.

Comment: `raw_json` should be defined as `jsonb` or at least `json`, not as `text`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Move the function to the FROM clause (where set-returning functions should be used). Then you can use `with ordinality` which also returns a column that indicates the index inside the array

```
select w.experience as we,
       w.experience ->> 'job_title' as "name",
       w.experience ->> 'job_description' as "description",
       w.idx as "index",
       rjt.uuid as uuid
from raw_json_table rjt
  left join json_array_elements(rjt.raw_json::json -> 'data' -> 'work_experience') with ordinality 
            as w(experience, idx) on true
```

The `left join` is necessary so that rows from `raw_json_table` that don't contain array elements are still included.